# Multiple charts with the same X Axis

Tags: teechart

I have three charts placed on top of each other and I would like them to all use the one X Axis. How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. The best option is using a single chart with 3 custom axis (or 1 standard and 2 custom axis) with different positioning for each one to define each series area. Custom axes are only supported in the Professional versions of TeeChart. Demos and tutorials about this functionality are inclued with both the registered and fully functional [evaluation version](http://www.steema.com/evaluation/vcl).
2. Hide the bottom axis of the top charts and eliminate panel margins, back walls and titles so there's no gap between charts.

For example:

```
uses Series;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Chart1.View3D:=False;
  Chart2.View3D:=False;

  Chart1.AddSeries(TLineSeries.Create(Self)).FillSampleValues;
  Chart2.AddSeries(TLineSeries.Create(Self)).FillSampleValues;

  Chart1.Axes.Bottom.Visible:=False;
  Chart1.MarginBottom:=0;
  Chart1.Walls.Back.Visible:=False;

  Chart2.Title.Visible:=False;
  Chart2.MarginTop:=0;
  Chart2.Walls.Back.Visible:=False;
  Chart2.Axes.Bottom.Grid.Visible:=False;
end;
```